# How to estimate similarity between sensor data based on the number of occurrence?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-science

Following is my sample data:

> data = {850.0: 6, -852.0: 5, 992.0: 29, -993.0: 25, 990.0: 27, -992.0: 28,
> 965.0: 127, 988.0: 37, -994.0: 24, 996.0: 14, -996.0: 19, -998.0: 19, 995.0: 17, 954.0: 71, -953.0: 64, 983.0: 48, 805.0: 20, 960.0: 97, 811.0: 23, 957.0: 98, 818.0: 9, -805.0: 10, -962.0: 128, 822.0: 5, 970.0: 115, 823.0: 6, 977.0: 86, 815.0: 11, 972.0: 118, -809.0: 3, -982.0: 77, 963.0: 129, 816.0: 15, 969.0: 131, 809.0: 13, -973.0: 115, 967.0: 141, 964.0: 110, 966.0: 141, -801.0: 11, -990.0: 33, 819.0: 8, 973.0: 113, -981.0: 71, 820.0: 16, 821.0: 10, -988.0: 42, 833.0: 7, 958.0: 92, -980.0: 98, 968.0: 138, -808.0: 5, -984.0: 57, 976.0: 108, 828.0: 3, -807.0: 6, 971.0: 134, -814.0: 3, 817.0: 13, -975.0: 112, 814.0: 12, 825.0: 6, 974.0: 90, -974.0: 125, -824.0: 2, -966.0: 131, -822.0: 4, 962.0: 108, -967.0: 121, -810.0: 3, 810.0: 11, 826.0: 7, 953.0: 74, -970.0: 140, -804.0: 6, -813.0: 2, 812.0: 18, 961.0: 126, -965.0: 159, -806.0: 5, 955.0: 74, -958.0: 93, -818.0: 6, 813.0: 18, 824.0: 6, 937.0: 25, -946.0: 51, -802.0: 8, 950.0: 48, -957.0: 91, 808.0: 11, 959.0: 116, -821.0: 3, -959.0: 108, 827.0: 4, -817.0: 4, 944.0: 47, -971.0: 126, -972.0: 104, -977.0: 96, 956.0: 92, 807.0: 10, 806.0: 21, 952.0: 60, 948.0: 51, 951.0: 67, 945.0: 47, -986.0: 37, 892.0: 13, 910.0: 23, 876.0: 6, -912.0: 18, 891.0: 8, 911.0: 22, -913.0: 13, 894.0: 7, 895.0: 12, 925.0: 15, 887.0: 6, 915.0: 16, 877.0: 7, 905.0: 14, 889.0: 7, -899.0: 10, 916.0: 17, -907.0: 11, -919.0: 17, 900.0: 20, 898.0: 9, 918.0: 16, 914.0: 18, 906.0: 18, 908.0: 17, -889.0: 7, 903.0: 16, 888.0: 5, -905.0: 9, -911.0: 19, 904.0: 20, -908.0: 12, 840.0: 2, -906.0: 16, 896.0: 11, -910.0: 17, -863.0: 3, 907.0: 27, -904.0: 10, -898.0: 13, 909.0: 19, -916.0: 20, 924.0: 24, 919.0: 20, -887.0: 6, 920.0: 12, 921.0: 12, 922.0: 15, 899.0: 14, -902.0: 9, -917.0: 12, 902.0: 14, 942.0: 46, 931.0: 23, 901.0: 22, -923.0: 14, -927.0: 15, 913.0: 18, -918.0: 16, 929.0: 22, 928.0: 13, -922.0: 7, -921.0: 16, 933.0: 22, 926.0: 13, 917.0: 18, 923.0: 16, 936.0: 24, 803.0: 30, -930.0: 10, 939.0: 33, -939.0: 24, 893.0: 8, 830.0: 5, 897.0: 8, 886.0: 8, -897.0: 4, -903.0: 12, -920.0: 9, -894.0: 3, -934.0: 14, 932.0: 23, -928.0: 16, 943.0: 40, 946.0: 45,
> 801.0: 17, -944.0: 35, 935.0: 23, 941.0: 30, -926.0: 11, -940.0: 38, 802.0: 16, 940.0: 43, -943.0: 38, -935.0: 24, 804.0: 23, -933.0: 9, -945.0: 36, 949.0: 56, 858.0: 2, -839.0: 3, -964.0: 108, -969.0: 111, -815.0: 2, 881.0: 3, -955.0: 74, -803.0: 3, 947.0: 50, -948.0: 57, -950.0: 58, -961.0: 133, -947.0: 43, -949.0: 54, -936.0: 20, 980.0: 75, -848.0: 3, -941.0: 27, -827.0: 5, -816.0: 7, -942.0: 37, 938.0:
> 29, -956.0: 81, -951.0: 59, -932.0: 11, -954.0: 71, -952.0: 64,
> -811.0: 3, 979.0: 89, -963.0: 128, -892.0: 4, -960.0: 109, 871.0: 4, 978.0: 85, -968.0: 136, 865.0: 1, -856.0: 3, 930.0: 11, 843.0: 5, -844.0: 1, -929.0: 24, -925.0: 19, -931.0: 11, 981.0: 65, 912.0: 19, 927.0: 10, -924.0: 8, -938.0: 25, 989.0: 31, -819.0: 4, 934.0: 16, -976.0: 92, -915.0: 14, 975.0: 92, 869.0: 5, 998.0: 9, 870.0: 1, -826.0: 2, 834.0: 2, 882.0: 5, 839.0: 4, 829.0: 3, 846.0: 2, -978.0: 117, -991.0: 39, -983.0: 59, -989.0: 48, 832.0: 4, 860.0: 5, -937.0:
> 25, 859.0: 1, 842.0: 5, -857.0: 4, -891.0: 8, 837.0: 4, -868.0: 3,
> -884.0: 4, 851.0: 4, 874.0: 8, 852.0: 6, 997.0: 14, -888.0: 3, 866.0: 6, -893.0: 6, -890.0: 6, 982.0: 45, 863.0: 2, 835.0: 3, -834.0: 3,
> -979.0: 73, 853.0: 3, 984.0: 44, -985.0: 30, 985.0: 36, 991.0: 25, 986.0: 35, -987.0: 29, 994.0: 24, 993.0: 29, -995.0: 16, -997.0: 17, -880.0: 4, -830.0: 3, 847.0: 1, 884.0: 4, -877.0: 5, -840.0: 1, -846.0: 2, -896.0: 8, -866.0: 2, -851.0: 2, -871.0: 2, -885.0: 3, -832.0: 3, -878.0: 1, 890.0: 6, 987.0: 22, -847.0: 2, 878.0: 5, 879.0: 3, 885.0: 5, 848.0: 2, 841.0: 5, 856.0: 3, 857.0: 4, 864.0: 1, 831.0:
> 5, 849.0: 3, 844.0: 3, 875.0: 3, 836.0: 3, 999.0: 6, -999.0: 6,
> -900.0: 7, 845.0: 2, 862.0: 1, 880.0: 4, 855.0: 2, -876.0: 1, -882.0: 2, -835.0: 2, -831.0: 5, -812.0: 1, -825.0: 2, -860.0: 3, -914.0: 12,
> -855.0: 5, -870.0: 5, -881.0: 4, -823.0: 3, -901.0: 5, -909.0: 15, -886.0: 2, 873.0: 3, -879.0: 1, -869.0: 4, -883.0: 4, -895.0: 8, 868.0: 3, -836.0: 2, 883.0: 4, -861.0: 2, -859.0: 2, -837.0: 1, -864.0: 2, -829.0: 2, -875.0: 4, -858.0: 2, -843.0: 1, -862.0: 1, -872.0: 2, 854.0: 2, -842.0: 1, -845.0: 3, -833.0: 1, -853.0: 3, 861.0: 3, -820.0: 2, -850.0: 2, -867.0: 2, -854.0: 1, -841.0: 3, 867.0: 1, -865.0: 3, -849.0: 2, 838.0: 1, -838.0: 1, -873.0: 1}

It is the `Key/Value` of a dictionary in Python. The `Keys` are the sensors data and the `Values` are the number of occurrences. I need to find if the two `Key/Value` match as in the following example:

`959.0: 116` and `-959.0: 108`

Here, the sensor data `959.0` and `-959.0` are repeated (occurred) `116` and `108` times, respectively. In my system, I can assume that `959.0` is good data. But it's not always the ideal case. The sensor data can be `958, -955, 952, etc` with their respective occurrence number. I need to find the good sensor data from my DB such that each data has similar opposite value and close number of occurrences are present.

My attempts:

At this moment, I'm solving it manually by plotting the data (x being the sensor data and y being the number of occurrence) and filtering it horizontally and vertically. For example:

```
    for key in list(data.keys()):  ## Filtering sensor data based on their difference on occurance times
        if ((-1*key) in data.keys() and abs(data[key]-data[(-1*key)])<2): 
        #if (-1*key) in data.keys(): 
            pass
        else: del data[key]
        
    #print(data)    
    for key in list(data.keys()):  ##Horizontal filter (based on number of occurance)
         if data[key] >20 or abs(key)>1000:
            pass
         else: del data[key]

lists = sorted(data.items()) # sorted by key, return a list of tuples


x, y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples

plt.plot(x, y,marker="*")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Is there any better statistical way to solve my problem in Python? Thank you.

Comment: Is the deletion of keys where `data[key] <= 20` supposed to happen before or after the finding of key pairs? I don't understand the point of finding pairs first if in the next step, one half of the pair might be deleted because that key's value is less than 20.

Comment: @AJH `data[key] <= 20` is just an example.

Comment: _"Is there any better statistical way to solve my problem in Python?"_ -- you might consider asking on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) to get more statistical expertise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly. You want to compare these two time-series data from sensors and do some analysis after that.

> But it's not always the ideal case. The sensor data can be 958, -955, 952, etc with their respective occurrence number.

And this sentence shows that there may be statistical errors in the data.

Plotting these time series at first could help you choose a good method.

[image]

The negative data is shown in orange and the positive is in blue.

```py
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = np.array(list(data_dict.items()), dtype=int)
positive = np.zeros((np.abs(data[:, 0]).max() + 1), dtype=int)
negative = np.zeros_like(positive)
positive[data[data[:, 0] > 0, 0]] = data[data[:, 0] > 0, 1]
negative[-data[data[:, 0] < 0, 0]] = data[data[:, 0] < 0, 1]
sns.lineplot(x=np.arange(len(positive)), y=savgol_filter(positive, 11, 3))
sns.lineplot(x=np.arange(len(positive)), y=savgol_filter(-negative, 11, 3))
plt.show()
```

And the diff you can see, statistical error depends on the value.

[image]

We can try to add a filter like the `Gaussian filter`, but here I prefer the `Savgol filter`.

You can use is from `scipy`.

```py
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
savgol_filter(negative, 11, 3)
```

[image]

And here is the diff.

[image]

Comment: Hi @FavorMylikes,
Could you provide the code snippet to generate the first image?

Comment: @santobedi update.

Comment: Thanks for the update. How can I store the filtered data into a dictionary (key:data at x-axis in the graph, value:data at the y-axis in the graph)?

Comment: @santobedi How about `{i:p for i,p in enumerate(savgol_filter(positive, 11, 3)) if p != 0}`, a single line code.

Comment: That worked. I could tune the filter to get only peaks (positive) and vallyes (negative) with my complete data set. These peaks-valleys pairs  fulfills my requirement. I'm trying to store them (peaks or valleys) in a dictionary such that I can use them in further process. How can I extract the peaks from the graph? Any idea?

Comment: @santobedi Try this method  [find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method of a pandas dataframe to calculate the data useful to filter the desired sensor with different degree of precision. Setting `axis=1` in this method allows to define a function that operates on each row.
For example you could use an approach similar to the one you are doing by hand:

1. Fix a threshold for sensors similarity
2. Fix a threshold for occurrences similarity
3. Fix a threshold for the number of similar sensor + occurrences that a single data point must have to be considered valid

For example, the first step can be performed as follow:

```
# The data variable is the one provided in the example
# Prepare Pandas dataframe
data_dict = {"sensor": list(), "occ": list()}
for k,v in data.items():
    data_dict["sensor"].append(k)
    data_dict["occ"].append(v)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

# Add support column for filtering
df["ct"] =  pd.NaT

# Chose sensor similarity threshold
threshold = 2

# Populate the column
df["ct"] = df.apply(lambda x: get_sensor_count(x, threshold, df), axis=1)
```

Where the function `get_sensor_count()` is implemented as follows:

```
# Get the count of "similar" sensors
def get_sensor_count(row, threshold, df):
    # First check if sensor hava similar value, then if they have opposite signs
    return df[(abs(abs(df["sensor"]) - abs(row["sensor"])) < threshold) & (df["sensor"] * row["sensor"] < 0)]["sensor"].count()
```

In this way you can set the threshold for sensor similarity and obtain the count of similar sensor. To filter the sensor that do not have similar opposite values you can do the following:

```
# If at least one silimar sensor, keep it
df_good_sensors = df[df["ct"] > 0]
```

After that you can add arbitrary filter on this dataset, such as the one in your example:

```
# Filter occurrences
df_good_occ = df_good_sensors[(df["occ"] > 20) | (abs(df["sensor"] > 1000))]
```

Now you can check what are the sensors that measured similar occurrences by setting a new threshold for this part of the data:

```
 # Chose occurrences similarity threshold
 o_threshold = 5 
 df_good_occ["ct"] = pd.NaT
 df_good_occ["ct"] = df_good_occ.apply(lambda x: get_occ_count(x, threshold, o_threshold, df_good_occ), axis=1)
```

Where the get_occ_count() function is implemented as follows:

```
def get_occ_count(row, s_threshold, o_threshold, df):
    # Get similar sensors using the previous sensor threshold
    to_check = df[(abs(abs(df["sensor"]) - abs(row["sensor"])) < s_threshold) & (df["sensor"] * row["sensor"] < 0)]
    # Count only the occurrences values similar to the current sensors
    return to_check[abs(to_check["occ"] - to_check["occ"]) < o_threshold]["sensor"].count()
```

Now for each sensor you have the number of opposite values that have a similar occurrences number. As a final filter, you can set how many similar data points each final point must have to be considered:

```
# Chose number of similar sensors to chose how many to keep
count_threshold = 2
df_final = df_good_occ[df_good_occ["ct"] > count_threshold]

# Drop support column
df_final.drop(["ct"], axis=1)
```

With this approach you have 3 possible parameters to set:

- the sensor threshold
- the occurrence threshold
- the number of similar data points

You can mix these 3 variables and see what gives you the better results. To test this, you can follow a process like the following:

- generate the 3 variables
- use a dataset in which you already know what data points must be kept
- see the % of data points that have been correctly kept